# Page is redirected back in selenium

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, testing, automation, selenium

I have a following code

```
    selenium.Open("/logon.aspx")
    selenium.type(strUsernameID, pUsername)
    selenium.type(strPasswordId, pPassword)
    selenium.Click(strButtonId)
    selenium.WaitForPageToLoad(600000)
    selenium.click("link=Home")
    selenium.system.threading.thread.sleep(300000)
    selenium.WaitForPageToLoad(600000)
```

But as soon as I click the home link its redirected back to login page. This code works fine with another URL. I tried by putting id, everything. but couldn't figure out why its behaving like this. Please help me out. as this works fine with other systems...just change the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell why there is thread sleep after the clicking the link? I think, the page may timeout after signing in.